# How do I bind a video to MediaElement's Source?

Tags: json, .net, data-binding, maui, mediaelement

I'm working off of James Montemagno's Monkey Finder app.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonkeysApp-Workshop

I'm trying to add a video to the details page, but I'm getting an error at runtime when I try to bind a new property called "Video" to the MediaElement Source. It works if I hardcode the file but not when I try to bind it, so MediaElement is set up correctly. It's just the binding that doesn't work.

The debugger breaks here:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

I added the attribute to the class:

```
public class Monkey
{
     ...     
     public string Video { get; set; }
}
```

I added the attribute and it's value to the json file for every entry:

```
{
     ...
     "Video": "testvid1.mp4"
},
```

I added the MediaElement to DetailsPage.xaml:

```
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="current_video"
WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="200"
Source="{Binding Monkey.Video}"
ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
ShouldAutoPlay="True"/>
```

It does not like the Source line. I found some related discussions about it online and it appears it may be a bug, but I can't make sense of the discussion or proposed workarounds as I'm fairly new to .NET.

Am I missing something obvious?

**---------------EDIT---------------**

I fixed the path to the video file, so I no longer trigger a break. However, **the video appears blank**.

This works:

```
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="current_video"
WidthRequest="700" HeightRequest="500"                                  
Source="embed://testvid1.mp4"
ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
ShouldAutoPlay="True"/>
```

This does not work:

```
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="current_video"
WidthRequest="700" HeightRequest="500"                                  
Source="{Binding Monkey.Video}"
ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
ShouldAutoPlay="True"/>
```

The Monkey class has a Video property of type string:

```
public class Monkey
{
...
    public string Video { get; set; }
}
```

The json file has a value assigned to that property:

```
{
...
    "Video": "embed://testvid1.mp4"
},
```

The video is located in Resources/Raw.

If it helps or changes the solution to this problem, I would prefer to store the videos on the Android device instead of inside the app. This is only going to run on Android and will only be used by me.

Contents of .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows')) and '$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' == 'Full'">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MonkeyFinder</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MonkeyFinder</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.monkeyfinder</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>ECD44DAE-B03E-4D8B-B427-71865961E696</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement" Version="3.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: "getting an error at runtime" - it helps a lot if you tell us what this error is

Comment: It breaks here:

#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif

Edit: Sorry if my terminology is off. It's been 10 years since I've programmed anything and I was mainly focused on C. This is a whole new world for me!

Comment: Please show the actual error message, not where it breaks. My best guess is that you need to provide a proper URI for the video. Where is the video stored? Is it local or remote? Note: What you call "attribute" is called a *property* in C#.

Comment: If I change the property to MediaElement instead of string as I've seen others suggest online, I get an actual error pop up on screen: "The JSON value could not be converted to CommunityToolkit.Maui.Views.MediaSource.Path: $[0].Video | LineNumber: 9 | BytePositionInLine: 31.

Comment: The video is stored in Resources/Raw. I see I didn't include the right path. I changed the Video value in the json file to be "embed://testvid1.mp4" instead of just "testvid1.mp4". No more errors, no more breaks. However, it only displays an empty video. There's no way to skip ahead or play it. I hardcoded "embed://testvid.mp4" as a test and it works that way, so it's still a binding issue it seems.

Comment: `(sender, e)` - `e` is the `Exception` object and will contain details about the cause of the exception

Comment: I no longer get an error. The video is blank though. See update above.

Comment: Instead of adding details in comments, please add them to the question. Can you show us what the relevant parts of your *.csproj* file look like, i.e. is the file added as a `MauiAsset`?

Comment: I edited the post. I'm not completely familiar with the file structure, so I'm unable to find a file with the extension of .csproj, if that's what you're asking for.

Comment: You can go to the folder of your app to find file `.csproj`. For your problem, have you tried other mp4 files?

Comment: Thanks, I added the contents of .csproj to the question.

Yes, I have tried three different ones. They all work when hardcoded, but not when I try to "bind" them.

Answer (score 0):

From document [Play local media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement?fbclid=IwAR10x83NfO5g6a8TnxfPsLujMvWli8eRodwpIUm7Prw8FSgBqejH0q5qsZ8#play-local-media), we could know that:

> Note
>
> The shorthand `embed://` and `filesystem://` only work from XAML. In code,
> please use `MediaSource.FromResource()` and `MediaSource.FromFile()`
> respectively. Using these methods, you can omit the  `embed://` and
> `filesystem://` prefixes. The rest of the path should be the same.

So, if you want to use databinding to achieve this, you can try to define a variable of type `MediaSource` and load the video using code `MediaSource.FromResource`.

```
    public MediaSource Source { get; set; }
```

Then we can load the video from folder `Resources/raw/testvid1.mp4` by using the following code:

```
    Source = MediaSource.FromResource("testvid1.mp4");
```

Usage example:

```
   <toolkit:MediaElement  
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="300"   
    x:Name="myMediaElement" 
    Source="{Binding Source}"
    ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True" />
```

Comment: Where should the "Source = ...;" line go? To bind it, wouldn't it need to go in the json file? If so, I already tried that (with different syntax of course).

Comment: `To bind it, wouldn't it need to go in the json file?`   You need to parse the Json data into the corresponding model data, and then bind it.